# elements of unordered list in the same line

Tags: html, css

I have unordered list like following

```
 <div>
  <ul>
    <li id="e1">element one</li>
    <li id="e2">element two</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

I want e1 and e2 to appear in the same line. And I don't want to use display:inline-block or inline

Is it possible and how?

Comment: I can think of at least 5 ways in CSS to do it without display inline-block or inline. But what's wrong with those?

Comment: @Alohci can you list them as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main alternative other than some tricky positioning is to use floats (and float clearing)

```
ul {
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
}
```

Comes with it's own annoying problems, but there it is.

It is not necessary to set a width unless you used display: block on those lis.  Which you might have since you said you didn't want to inline them (which they are by default).

Of course there are many other list styles to consider like margin, padding, and the list-style* ones.

Comment: Also if it's unacceptable to have overflow: hidden; on the UL (it often is if you need something to protrude out of the menu) you can use an alternative float clearing technique if required.  Float clearing means to force a container to wrap around the float elements within it, and usually affects the height of the container and prevents things further down on the page overlapping the menu.

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting the width and float the list left.

```
ul li{
 width: 100px;
 float: left;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/27krdjp2/)

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#e1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
#e2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li id="e1">element one</li>
    <li id="e2">element two</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```